# Automate bootstrap datepicker using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, datepicker, webdriver, bootstrap-datepicker

I tried to automate but the locators are not visible and the div class is appending dynamically.Can any one help me out??

Comment: Can you show us some of your work please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Friends I automated the bootstrap date picker. I am sharing the code may be this help anyone like me.

```
   driver.findElement(By.id("datepicker")).click();//to click on thedate picker field
    String date_ent = "17-May-2017";
    String date_ent1[] = date_ent.split("-");
    String shipFDay = date_ent1[0];
    String shipFMonth = date_ent1[1];
    String shipFYear = date_ent1[2];
 String date_pres = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//th[@title='Select Month']")).getText();
 System.out.println(date_pres);
    String dp[] = date_pres.split(" ");
    String month_pres = dp[0];
    String year_pres = dp[1];
    if (year_pres.equals(shipFYear)) {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//th[@title='Select Month']")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'" + shipFMonth + "')]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);

    } else if (Integer.parseInt(year_pres) > Integer.parseInt(shipFYear)) {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//th[@title='Select Month']")).click();

        while (2 > 1) {
            year_pres = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//th[@title='Select Year']")).getText();
            if (year_pres.equalsIgnoreCase(shipFYear)) {

                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'" + shipFMonth + "')]")).click();
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                break;
            }
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@title='Previous Year']")).click();
        }

    } else {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//th[@title='Select Month']")).click();
        while (2 > 1) {
            year_pres = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//th[@title='Select Year']")).getText();
            if (year_pres.equalsIgnoreCase(shipFYear)) {

                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'" + shipFMonth + "')]")).click();

                Thread.sleep(5000);
                break;
            }
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@title='Next Year']")).click();
        }
    }

    switch (shipFMonth) {
    case "Jan": {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@data-day='01/" + shipFDay + "/" + shipFYear + "']")).click();
        System.out.println("Date Selected");
        break;
    }

    case "Feb": {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@data-day='02/" + shipFDay + "/" + shipFYear + "']")).click();
        System.out.println("Date Selected");
        break;
    }
    case "Mar": {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@data-day='03/" + shipFDay + "/" + shipFYear + "']")).click();
        System.out.println("Date Selected");
        break;
    }
    case "Apr": {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@data-day='04/" + shipFDay + "/" + shipFYear + "']")).click();
        System.out.println("Date Selected");
        break;
    }
    case "May": {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@data-day='05/" + shipFDay + "/" + shipFYear + "']")).click();
        System.out.println("Date Selected");
        break;
    }
    case "Jun": {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@data-day='06/" + shipFDay + "/" + shipFYear + "']")).click();
        System.out.println("Date Selected");
        break;
    }
    case "Jul": {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@data-day='07/" + shipFDay + "/" + shipFYear + "']")).click();
        System.out.println("Date Selected");
        break;
    }
    case "Aug": {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@data-day='08/" + shipFDay + "/" + shipFYear + "']")).click();
        System.out.println("Date Selected");
        break;
    }
    case "Sep": {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@data-day='09/" + shipFDay + "/" + shipFYear + "']")).click();
        System.out.println("Date Selected");
        break;
    }
    case "Oct": {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@data-day='10/" + shipFDay + "/" + shipFYear + "']")).click();
        System.out.println("Date Selected");
        break;
    }
    case "Nov": {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@data-day='11/" + shipFDay + "/" + shipFYear + "']")).click();
        System.out.println("Date Selected");
        break;
    }
    case "Dec": {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@data-day='12/" + shipFDay + "/" + shipFYear + "']")).click();
        System.out.println("Date Selected");
        break;
    }
    default: {
        System.out.println("Please enter the date in the standard format like DD-MMM-yyyy");
     break;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

have you considered calling the "update" method via JS to set the date? => https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#update
I was able to set the date via the console using the following command, "$('#sandbox-container div').datepicker('update', '2011-03-05');" => https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=embedded&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&maxViewMode=4&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox

With that, you can use the JavascriptExecutor to fire off the command

Answer (score 0):

```
            public void testDAtePicker() throws Exception {
            //Take a String variable for input
            String sdate = "4/mar/2021";
            
            //Take a String array and split date/month/your
    String date_dd_MM_yyyy[] = (sdate.split(" ")[0]).split("/");
            
            //Click the date picker element to open calendar
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='sandbox-container1']/div/span/i")).click();

            //Click to open year list and month list
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/table/thead/tr[2]/th[2]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/table/thead/tr[2]/th[2]")).click();
    
    // Select a year from the calendar
            // Take list of webelemnts and proper tag to get actual values from a main element
    List<WebElement> yearlist = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/table/tbody"))
            .findElements(By.tagName("span"));
    for (int i = 0; i < yearlist.size(); i++) {
        if (yearlist.get(i).getText().equalsIgnoreCase(date_dd_MM_yyyy[2])) {
            yearlist.get(i).click();
            System.out.println("Year found successfully..");
            break;
        } else if (i == yearlist.size()) {
            System.out.println("Year not found.");
        }
    }
    
            //Select a month from the calendar
            // Take list of webelemnts and proper tag to get actual values from a main element
    List<WebElement> monthkist = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/table/tbody"))
            .findElements(By.tagName("span"));
    for (int i = 0; i < monthkist.size(); i++) {
        if (monthkist.get(i).getText().equalsIgnoreCase(date_dd_MM_yyyy[1])) {
            monthkist.get(i).click();
            System.out.println("Month found successfully..");
            break;
        } else if (i == yearlist.size()) {
            System.out.println("Month not found.");
        }
    }
    
             //Select a date from the calendar
             // Take list of webelemnts and proper tag to get actual values from a main element
    List<WebElement> datelist = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/table/tbody"))
            .findElements(By.tagName("td"));
    for (int i = 0; i < datelist.size(); i++) {
        if (datelist.get(i).getText().equalsIgnoreCase(date_dd_MM_yyyy[0])) {
            datelist.get(i).click();
            System.out.println("Date found successfully..");
            break;
        } else if (i == yearlist.size()) {
            System.out.println("Date not found.");
        }
    }
```